# Search functionality within an AngularJs Website

Tags: angularjs, search, web, web-crawler

How to implement a search bar which will search contents within my website? My website is written in AngularJs.

Answer (score 0):

I hope [this plunkr will help you to get some head start](https://plnkr.co/edit/kILkSyOBeW5tY9xzBtcp?p=preview)

```
<input type="text" 
      ng-model="customSelected" placeholder="Custom template" 
      uib-typeahead="state as state.name for state in statesWithFlags | filter:{name:$viewValue}" 
      typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html" 
      class="form-control" 
      typeahead-show-hint="true" 
      typeahead-min-length="0">
```

I have used `ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js` for this angular implementation.